# zigbee motion detect sensor usage

Tags: zigbee

My prior experience is able to receive the data sent from my temperature / humidity zigbee sensor. 
Also, I am able to send the command to control the zigbee power meter/switch.

I bought a motion detect sensor with a document contains a line of IAS packet.
I know it's a IAS ZONE device.

Could anyone let me know what is the first step to handle with this kinda sensor?

I just enabled the permit-join 255 on my zigbee gateway but the motion detect sensor seems not to join the network.

Thanks

@tc,

After trying two more times to join the network, it finally works.
Thanks for your reply and I will work on the steps as you provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you say it is not joining the network, have you verified with a packet sniffer that it is not joining and sending a device announce, or is it not sending reports or responding to read attributes in the same way as your temp/humidity sensors?

If it is really not joining then there maybe a button on the IAS device that will trigger a join. Or it may already be connected to a network and need resetting.

After you have joined the IAS Zone device to the network the IAS device will not automatically send reports like the temp/humidity sensors. You will need to enroll it first. Do this by writing the CIE IEEE Address attribute for the IAS Zone Endpoint and set it to the IEEE address of you Gateway (or CIE). You may need to discover the endpoint ID with active EP request, and Simple Descriptor Request. After setting the CIE IEEE Address attribute it should then send a Zone Enrollment Request, you should send a Zone Enrollment Response and then the IAS Zone device will send Gateway/CIE Zone State Change Notifications when an Alarm or other Zone event is triggered.

For more info on the CIE IEEE Address attribute and the Zone Enrollment Req/Rsp refer to the ZCL Specification http://www.zigbee.org/download/standards-zigbee-cluster-library/.

Regards,
TC.

Comment: I know that different zigbee gateways have thier own approach to implement. However, is there any sample code for IAS_ZONE available on line? so I can get more clear with your answer.

Comment: There is no standard ZigBee API. All stacks have a different API, but also API's at different levels. Some may require you to send raw ZCL frames in an aFDataRequest, others will have a ZCL API with different parameter. So it is not possible to supply sample code.

I advise that you contact the supplier of the ZigBee stack for this level of support. If this is Texas Instruments ZStack then this support is available at:
https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/158

TC.