# zigbee IAS device enroll and response

Tags: zigbee

From the post ( link shown below )

[zigbee motion detect sensor usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151625/zigbee-motion-detect-sensor-usage)
,

Currently I have a Zigbee IAC ZONE (CIE) device which is a coordinator and  a IAS ZONE device which is a motion sensor. I dont have a IAS WD device yet. My thinking is that my motion sensor needs to be enrolled with my IAS ZONE - CIE device. After this, my CIE device should response to the IAS ZONE device so that the connection is established.

Compare to the temp / humidity sensor, it uses the standard ZCLReport as a callback function to process the data. How about the IAS Zone device ?

1. What is the callback function I should implement in my IAS ZONE-CIE cluster?
2. How can I do the "enrollment" ? I thought it is ZCLRead function but my testing did not work.
3. How can IAS CIE device response ? ( My assumption is ZCLWrite function)

There might be different implementations on each zigbee stack. If any stack information related to this topic is available ( maybe TI-Z stack ?), please let me know how it works on this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you may need the following steps.

1. Implement an Enrollment() function which you need to check the API manual about how your stack provide to do this.
2. Implement the EnrollRequestResp() within the Enrollment function. This makes the enrollment complete.
3. Implement the ChangeNotification() function. The API you need to go through your API manual.